# CAML cannot reference Custom Properties in custom fields

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to create a custom field type in SharePoint. 
My custom field type has a custom property called CustomProperty.

```
<FieldTypes>
  <FieldType>
    <Field Name="TypeName">CustomField</Field>
    <Field Name="InternalType">CustomField</Field>
    ..............................
    ..............................
    <PropertySchema>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="CustomProperty" DisplayName="CustomProperty" Type="Text" Hidden="TRUE" />
      </Fields>
      <RenderPattern Name="DisplayPattern">
      <Property Select="CustomProperty" />
    </RenderPattern>
  </FieldType>
</FieldTypes>
```

I am trying to render the value of this custom property in the DisplayPattern.

But it looks like the CAML is not able to reference the custom properties.

I am not getting any value for the CustomValue property even though it is set correctly.

Any idea how to refer custom properties in CAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no straightforward way of achieving this, from what I've seen.

Your best option is to look at using this.[GetCustomProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.getcustomproperty.aspx)("CustomProperty") within the overrided [GetFieldValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.getfieldvalue.aspx) function (or GetFieldValueAsHtml for a Note field).

The value string passed into the GetFieldValue function is the output from your CAML, so you can append to it and pass it on out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample:

http://blogs.msdn.com/toddca/archive/2009/01/23/customizing-the-rendering-of-a-custom-spfield.aspx

I haven’t tried it myself, and I have no idea if changing the SchemaXml could cause any unexpected problems.